# Corrected road model to conform to earth curvature

Tags: modeling, mesh, uv

I have a 3D road model created in Blender, with a total length of less than 30km. I want to place this model into a 3D Earth system for presentation. However, I noticed that after placing it into the 3D Earth system, the model does not bend with the curvature of the Earth, resulting in an incorrect representation (some parts of the model may be submerged under the surface or floating in the air), as shown in the image.

[image]

How can I make adjustments in Blender to ensure that my road model conforms to the curvature of the Earth?[part of road model](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mUsIDdljNJRJsKHrG_aDo4i-n6sSRW2J/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: have you tried using the shrinkwrap modifier

Comment: no I haven't. That is great idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your earth is completely spherical, you could:

Join all your object into one, align it with the X axis, set the origin to the center, put an empty at the same location, rotate it -90° on Y:

[image]

Give your object a *Simple Deform* modifier, *Bend* mode, *Axis* Y, with the empty as *Origin*:

[image]

Increase the *Angle* until you have the bend you want:

[image]

You could also use a *Curve* modifier with a curve circle as *Curve Object*.

Comment: In fact, this is the method I am currently using, although there are still some minor imperfections in certain sections of the road model (due to the Earth not being a perfect sphere), the overall effect is still good!

Comment: what you can do is apply the modifier then correct manually